# How to get the use device input or output status by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to get use device input or out status and return status by python.
Can you help me? I use this pyusb:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys
import usb.core
# find USB devices
dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
# loop through devices, printing vendor and product ids in decimal and hex
for cfg in dev:
  sys.stdout.write('Decimal VendorID=' + str(cfg.idVendor) + ' & ProductID=' + str(cfg.idProduct) + '\n')
  sys.stdout.write('Hexadecimal VendorID=' + hex(cfg.idVendor) + ' & ProductID=' + hex(cfg.idProduct) + '\n\n')
```

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us a bit more about what your problem is? How is your code not working? Does it result in an error?

Comment: that is a example,i want to know how to use python to get usb device input or output status,thanks

Comment: Ah, I was wondering what "use device" meant. Is this a typo? You meant to say "usb device"?